# alert not popping up in php

Tags: javascript, php

In a particular php file iam using a header and an alert box before it executes header, but its neglecting alert and executing header directly..!!please help me resolving this...!!pardon if i went wrong somewere.
  **.php**

```
<?php
header('location: formprofile.php');
session_start();
        require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();

        // json response array
        $response = array("error" => false);
        if (!empty($_POST['salutation']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['dob']) && !empty($_POST['mobile']) && !empty($_POST['country']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['pin'])){
                /*
                if required include seperate validation
                for some fields which require validation
                */
                // receiving the post params
                $salutation = ($_POST['salutation']);
                $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
                $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
                $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
                $mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']);
                $country = trim($_POST['country']);
                $state = trim($_POST['state']);
                $city = trim($_POST['city']);
                $pin = trim($_POST['pin']);

                /*
                validation process
                starts from here
                */

                // validate your email address
               if(strlen($mobile) == 10){

                  if($db->isMobileNumberExisted($mobile)) {
                         //user already existed
                         $response["error"] = true;
                         $response["error_msg"] = "user already existed with" . $mobile;
                         echo json_encode($response);
                   }else{  
                           // create a new user
                           $user = $db->storeUser($salutation, $fname, $lname, $dob, $mobile, $country, $state, $city, $pin);
                           if ($user) {
                               // user stored successfully
                               $response["error"] = false;
                               $_SESSION['fullname'] = $user['fullname'];
                               $_SESSION['vault_no'] = $user['vault_no'];
                                                                        $message = "Registration successful";
                               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

                             } else {
                                // user failed to store
                                $response["error"] = true;
                                $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                                echo json_encode($response);
                             }
                       }

                }else{
                        //invalid mobile number
                        $response["error"] = true;
                        $response["error_msg"] = "PLEASE ENTER VALID MOBILE NUMBER!";
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    }

        }else{
               //missing the required fields
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Please fill all the required parameters!";
                echo json_encode($response);
          }

?>
```

Comment: Are you want to redirect this page to `formprofile.php` ?

Comment: yes sir but want an alert before it redirects..!! cant it happen without using other ajax thing..!!

Comment: show what you have done in js file ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('location: formprofile.php');
```

This line is redirecting the page to `formprofile.php` and that causes to ignore everything below it. Just remove that line or if you want redirect after execution, then move it to the end of the file and do not echo or print anything before it.

But if you want to have some alert before redirecting to other page don't use `header()` for redirect. Add this JavaScript at the end of the file.

```
?>
<script>
    alert("your message");
    document.location = "formprofile.php";
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry sir but i want it to move to another location after execution..!! is it not possible..??

Comment: Yes, then move it to the end of the file and do not echo or print anything before it.

Comment: or make the redirection by javascript in client side.

Comment: @Sarath yes, including it.